# How to get a month index from its 3-letter abbreviation in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, date, datatable

I am trying to retrieve the month number from the month abbreviation (e.g., Jan, Feb, Mar). Here is what I have tried:

```
xdata(i) = DateTime.Parse(
               filteredData.Columns(i + 23).ColumnName.ToString
           ).ToString("m")
```

The **filteredData** is a DataTable that has column names labeled as month abbreviations.
What's the best way to retrieve the month number in this case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Somthing like,

```
Dim monthNumber = DateTime.ParseExact(
                      "Jan",
                      "MMM",
                      CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month
```

Where, `"Jan"` is a valid abbreviation for a month where you run your code.

Comment: And can I wrap that around with Integer.Parse to convert the DateTime to an integer value?

Comment: @SillyCoda, the `Month` property is an `Integer` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.datetime.month.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1